# Titanium - Custom Map Annotation Bubbles?

Tags: iphone, annotations, titanium

Is there any way to customize the map annotation bubbles in Appcelerator Titanium? Specifically, I'd like them to be able to display more text than what they show (ideally, by expanding to fit the text). I know I can make them clickable and take the user to a page with more info, but I simply don't have enough information to warrant that. It's basically just the title text is too long (and I can't change the text itself, it comes from sources I have no control over).

Alternatively (if customizing what's there isn't an option), is there an easy way to do custom bubbles? I don't really want to have to reinvent the wheel and rewrite the pins themselves and their event handlers, but if it comes down to it (and someone can point me to some code that can get me started, since I know if it's required, someone's done it), then so be it.

iPhone-specific options are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment the latest Titanium SDK gives you such **possibilities** for annotation bubble customization:

1. Add subtitle for the bubble (**subtitle** option). You will see additional text under the title. On Android subtitle can be multiline (using '\n').
2. Add left and right view to the bubble (**leftView\rightView** options). You can add custom view to the left or right part of the bubble. And view can consist of different elements (label, image...).

Read more [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Map.Annotation-object).

If this is enough for your task - you can use it. But for deeper customization you must create your own view and show it on annotation click event.

Comment: Please thoroughly read my question. I already explained that I understand that you can do the title/subtitle (and considering my tags say **iPhone**, Android's ability to do multi-line doesn't do me any good, especially considering the same behavior is not possible on iPhone from what I've found). The "custom view" doesn't do any good, either, given it's intended for an image/link and is still confined to the dimensions of the *bubble* itself.

Comment: @Shauna I don't see that you understand how to make subtitle in your question ;). I have written all standart possibilities for customizing annotation and I don't exactly know how you want to customize the bubble. If you want full customization then 'you must create your own view and show it on annotation click event'.

Comment: Yeah, we figured that out a while back and just switched to Google Maps so we could have control over the look. I was also hoping, at the time I asked this question, someone had come up with/found a plugin or relatively easy way to make their own map annotations, but it seems no one has.